# What does "fatal: bad revision" mean?

Tags: git

In the context:

```
git revert HEAD~2 myFile
fatal: bad revision '/Users/rose/gitTest/myFile'
```

I'm sure HEAD~2 exists.

**EDIT** Amber is correct. I meant to use `reset` instead of `revert`.

Comment: @AD7six, Rose Perrone - sorry, just my default response to seeing people edit in notes about answers to questions. :) Hadn't checked any further. Cheers!

Answer (score 92, accepted):

If you only want to revert a single file to its state in a given commit, you actually want to use the `checkout` command:

```
git checkout HEAD~2 myFile
```

---

The `revert` command is used for reverting entire commits (and it doesn't revert you *to* that commit; it actually just reverts the changes *made* by that commit - if you have another commit after the one you specify, the later commit won't be reverted).

Comment: Fantastic, worked like a charm. I could add that you can also specify the hash of a specific commit (that was my case) instead of HEAD~2 if you want a specific version of the file.

Answer (score 20):

I was getting this error in IntelliJ, and none of these answers helped me. So here's how I solved it.

Somehow one of my sub-modules added a `.git` directory. All git functionality returned after I deleted it.

Comment: Yeah that worked for me. The thing is if you are managing your module with composer, the next update will probably create the `.git` again.

Comment: I set the Version Control preference in IntelliJ to `/Users/myusername/Developer/myProject/` instead of `<Project>` and the error went away for me as well. Some other folders had `.git` in it and IntelliJ must have gotten confused.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me as well! I had another repository included into the main repo (on purpose) and PyCharm was confused, but just for several files.

Answer (score 8):

`git revert` doesn't take a filename parameter.  Do you want `git checkout`?

Answer (score 6):

I had a "fatal : bad revision" with Idea / Webstorm because I had a git directory inside another, without using properly submodules or subtrees.

I checked for `.git` dirs with :

```
find ./ -name '.git' -print
```

Answer (score 4):

### Git revert only accepts commits

From the docs:

> Given one or more existing commits, revert the changes that the related patches introduce ...

`myFile` is intepretted as a commit - because `git revert` doesn't accept file paths; only commits

### Change one file to match a previous commit

To change one file to match a previous commit - use `git checkout`

```
git checkout HEAD~2 myFile
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Intellij. The issue was that someone added the file that I am trying to compare in Intellij to .gitignore, without actually deleting the file from Git.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you specifying `myFile` there?

Git revert reverts the commit(s) that you specify.

```
git revert HEAD~2
```

reverts the `HEAD~2` commit

```
git revert HEAD~2 myfile
```

reverts `HEAD~2` AND `myFile`

I take `myFile` is a file that you want to revert? In that case use

`git checkout HEAD~2 -- myFile`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete any commit then you might need to use git rebase command

git rebase -i HEAD~2

it will show you last 2 commit messages, if you delete the commit message and save that file deleted commit will automatically disappear...

Answer (score 0):

in my case I had an inconsistent state where the file in question (with the bad commit hash) was not actually added to Git, this clashed somehow with IntelliJ's state.
Manually adding the file using git on the command line fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of this, and git was complaining that the pathspec of the file I was trying to checkout was unknown.

The easiest fix for me was to delete the already versioned file locally and revert to the versioned version.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was in the wrong directory and did not even notice

Answer (score 0):

I used `git revert 3d4a5bc` and received the same fatal: bad revision error.

In my case it was a problem with **git bash** terminal inside VS Code, I switched to default CMD Windows terminal (also inside VS Code), and the command worked great!